# unable to insert data into oracle database using rjdbc

Tags: r, oracle

```
//creating table   
    createTab <- "create table REVIEWS(serial number, medicine 
        varchar2(30),reviews varchar2(200))"
//inserting values in table
        insStr <- "insert into REVIEWS(serial,medicine,reviews) values(:1,:2,:3)";
    x<-2;
    y<-"aspirin";
    z<-"okay";
    dbGetQuery(con, insStr,data.frame(x,y,z));
```

I am trying to storing data in database but getting the following error

> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
>             Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for insert into REVIEWS(serial,medicine,reviews) values(:1,:2,:3) (Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2)